# Convert Array of arrays to segments in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3, uisegmentedcontrol

I have array `[["PT"], ["GE", "DE", "PL", "BY"], ["CZ", "US"]]` and I'd like to use it in `UISegmentedControl` that I created programmatically:

```
 for i in 0..<array.count {
            mySegmentControl.insertSegment(withTitle: array[i], at: i, animated: false)
        }
```

I see error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String?'

It's true, But I need that `PT` would be at first segment title, `GE..BY` at second and etc.

Comment: The segment titles are strings, not arrays. What result do you expect? What should the title of the second segment be?

Comment: @MartinR I know, but how to do so `PT` as String would be at first segment, `GE..BY` at second and etc..generate so count segments as count of arrays in main array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the type of array? Is it [[String]], then you can do this (Playground code):

```
extension UISegmentedControl {

    func updateTitle(array titles: [[String]]) {

        removeAllSegments()
        for t in titles {
            let title = t.joined(separator: ", ")
            insertSegment(withTitle: title, at: numberOfSegments, animated: true)
        }

    }
}

let control = UISegmentedControl()
control.updateTitle(array: [["PT"], ["GE", "DE", "PL", "BY"], ["CZ", "US"]])
control.titleForSegment(at: 1)
```

Comment: thanks, but I need that `PT` would be at first segment, `GE..BY` at second and etc..so, generate so count segments as count of arrays in main array

Comment: Then @Nirav D answered your new question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `PT` would be at first segment, `GE..BY` at second and etc.. So try like this.

```
for (index,subArray) in array.enumerated() {
     if subArray.count > 1 {
          let title = subArray.first! + ".." + subArray.last!
          mySegmentControl.insertSegment(withTitle: title, at: index, animated: false)
     }
     else if subArray.count > 0 {
          let title = subArray.first!
          mySegmentControl.insertSegment(withTitle: title, at: index, animated: false)
     }
}
```

Comment: @VadimNikolaev Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to map your arrays to the titles, like this:

```
let titles: [String] = array.flatMap {
    guard let first = $0.first else { return nil }
    return first + ($0.count > 1 ? (".." + $0.last!) : "")
}
```

which, for `let array = [["PT"], ["GE", "DE", "PL", "BY"], [], ["CZ", "US"]]` would yield `["PT", "GE..BY", "CZ..US"]`.

And then insert it in your `UISegmentedControl`:

```
titles.enumerated().forEach {
    mySegmentControl.insertSegment(withTitle: $0.element, at: $0.offset, animated: false)
}
```